# My iPhone SE has ceased booting up upon power-on

Tags: iphone

My iPhone SE had difficulty in upgrading to IOS 12.0.1. A visit to my local Apple store solved this problem.  Four days later, after turning off the phone for the evening, I turned power on, the Apple symbol appeared, but the software would not complete loading.  I tried the hard reset (Power on and home button held simultaneously,) the phone rebooted, and the Apple symbol appeared, but the iPhone hung and would not complete the reboot.  I believe I need an appointment again at my local Apple store. I would like your opinion before I call and make an appointment.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Get your hardware in the hands of a trained technician is the best plan. Asking on an Internet site to go through triage is so fraught with assumption issues / time lag issues. You’ll get more done in 15 minutes with a pro than weeks here in most cases.

This site isn’t a replacement for Apple support for lots of reasons mentioned here:

- [Why we're not customer support for [company X or product Y]](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y)